# Unable to awaken Debian 12 Linux under sleep/suspend. Requesting assistance to resolve

Tags: kde, debian-bookworm

Experiencing inability to recover Debian Linux 12 from sleep/suspend, forcing me to reboot in order to continue working.

1. Attempted to retest by placing the system in systemctl suspend, or systemctl sleep: issue seems to occur intermittently.
2. Checked dmesg for more information:
   Code:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep suspend
[    0.514148] Low-power S0 idle used by default for system suspend
[    1.379352] nvme 0000:02:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
[ 5855.586270] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
[ 5855.862453] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[ 7225.802165] PM: suspend exit
[11080.193594] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
[11080.215263] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[35093.125067] PM: suspend exit
[37895.111464] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
[37895.386443] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[44845.543060] PM: suspend exit
[45053.185169] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
[45053.201087] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[45069.500102] PM: suspend exit
[46289.903788] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
[46289.920093] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[49377.170125] PM: suspend exit
```

Code:

```
$ sudo dmesg --human | grep suspend
[  +0.229068] Low-power S0 idle used by default for system suspend
[  +0.013769] nvme 0000:02:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
[  +0.882861] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
[  +0.000008] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[  +0.119058] PM: suspend exit
[  +0.875629] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
[  +0.000006] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[  +0.110488] PM: suspend exit
[  +0.913437] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
[  +0.000009] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[  +0.120776] PM: suspend exit
[  +0.586198] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
[  +0.000005] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[  +0.129249] PM: suspend exit
[  +0.622130] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
[  +0.000005] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[  +0.125535] PM: suspend exit
```

Code:

```
$ sudo uname -a
Linux scion0829 6.5.0-0.deb12.1-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.5.3-1~bpo12+1 (2023-10-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Code:

```
$ neofetch
       _,met$$$$$gg.          XXXXXXX@XXXXXXX 
    ,g$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$P.       ------------------------ 
  ,g$$P"     """Y$$.".        OS: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) x86_64 
 ,$$P'              `$$$.     Host: 82XF IdeaPad Slim 5 16IRL8 
',$$P       ,ggs.     `$$b:   Kernel: 6.5.0-0.deb12.1-amd64 
`d$$'     ,$P"'   .    $$$    Uptime: 14 hours, 41 mins 
 $$P      d$'     ,    $$P    Packages: 3566 (dpkg), 15 (flatpak) 
 $$:      $$.   -    ,d$$'    Shell: bash 5.2.15 
 $$;      Y$b._   _,d$P'      Resolution: 1920x1200 
 Y$$.    `.`"Y$$$$P"'         DE: Plasma 5.27.5 
 `$$b      "-.__              WM: KWin 
  `Y$$                        WM Theme: Vivid-Blur-Dark-Aurorae 
   `Y$$.                      Theme: [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
     `$$b.                    Icons: [Plasma], breeze-dark [GTK2/3] 
       `Y$$b.                 Terminal: mate-terminal 
          `"Y$b._             Terminal Font: Monospace 12 
              `"""            CPU: 13th Gen Intel i7-1355U (12) @ 5.000GHz 
                              GPU: Intel Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics] 
                              Memory: 11735MiB / 15713MiB


XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

3. Checked online for more information: no information found for issue for KDE and Debian 12:

Code:

```
$ inxi -b
System:
  Host: scion0829 Kernel: 6.5.0-0.deb12.1-amd64 arch: x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: KDE Plasma v: 5.27.5 Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 82XF v: IdeaPad Slim 5 16IRL8
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: SDK0T76463 WIN
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: LENOVO v: LACN22WW date: 02/17/2023
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 47.8 Wh (86.4%) condition: 55.3/56.6 Wh (97.8%)
CPU:
  Info: 10-core (2-mt/8-st) 13th Gen Intel Core i7-1355U [MST AMCP]
    speed (MHz): avg: 1534 min/max: 400/5000:3700
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: Chicony Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.9 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: iris gpu: i915
    resolution: 1920x1200~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 22.3.6 renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (RPL-P)
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek driver: rtw89_8852be
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 68.56 GiB (14.4%)
Info:
  Processes: 367 Uptime: 14h 50m Memory: 15.35 GiB used: 11.99 GiB (78.1%)
  Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.26


XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

4. Checked online for dmesg message "Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug): no information seemed to be available.
5. Checked /etc and /sys to find anything that might point to the issue: nothing seemed to point to anything that I could use to resolve issue.

If someone could assist me on this, that would be most appreciated!